# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de una propiedad css de un elemento html?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando obtener el valor de una propiedad pero no se guarda dentro de la variable que creo con javascript. Me gustaría saber cómo obtener el valor de propiedades css de los elementos. ¿Acaso hay alguna función específica para eso en javaScript?

Por ejemplo:

```
<script>
        var visibility=document.getElementById("idDiv").style.visibility;
        document.write(visibility);

    </script>

    <div id="idDiv" style="visibility: hidden;">Este div está visible</div>

    <div id="idDiv2">Por tanto este DIV también lo está</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div id="idDiv" style="visibility: hidden;">Este div está visible</div>

<div id="idDiv2">Por tanto este DIV también lo está</div>

<script>
  var visibility=document.getElementById("idDiv").style.visibility;
  document.write(visibility);
</script>
```

Lo estabas realizando correctamente, pero al tener el `<script>` por encima del **HTML** en el momento de tratar de capturar el elemento con **JS** no existe elemento que capturar porque no ha cargado todavía.

Recuerda que en programación, la ejecución de un programa es secuencial, al igual que no llamarías al valor de una variable antes de inicializarla, tampoco se puede llamar a un elemento que no ha cargado en el **DOM**.

Para evitar este tipo de problemas se suele optar o bien por cargar los **scripts** de **JS** al final del **HTML** (antes de cerrar la etiqueta del `body`) o bien por usar una función específica que se ejecute una vez el **DOM** haya terminado de cargar ([window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload))